# Javascript - Shorthand method of getting element by ID

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid, addeventlistener

I accidentally did the following and to my surprise it worked!

```
one.addEventListener('mouseover', myFunction);
```

I am assuming this is a shorthand way of doing the following:

```
document.getElementById('one').addEventListener('mouseover', myFunction);
```

I am wondering are the two equivalent and will this work in any browser?

Comment: Older standards say that elements having an ID become properties of the Window object with the same name. It is maintained for backwards compatibility, but you shouldn't rely on it.

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have a variable "one" defined before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is totally possible, this is already answered in details here:

[Do DOM tree elements with ids become global variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/do-dom-tree-elements-with-ids-become-global-variables)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both should work in any browser.

A truly short hand method of this would be to use jquery:

```
$("#one").on("mouseover", *yourfunctionname*);
```

or

```
$("#one").on("click", function(){
//your function code
});
```